# Add subtitle to tab in tableView using appcelerator titanium

Tags: tabs, properties, titanium, tableview, appcelerator

i have a table view containing multiple tabs, on this tabs i want to add picutre, title and a description lets say as a subtitle. Im new in the appcelerator environment and i have no idea how to add a subtitle, didn't find anything on google, thanks alot..heres my code

```
var data = [
    {leftImage:'images/squiggle.png',title:'Puppy', hasChild:true,test:'/picture_events.js'},
    {leftImage:'images/squiggle.png',title:'Fish', hasChild:true,test:'/picture_events.js'}
];
```

what is the property i can add that let me add a subtitle on the tab ??

Comment: You have to add a label in Table row for showing description.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to do this you have to create a more complex row.

See this section of the appcelerator wiki

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Using+TableViews#UsingTableViews-Improvingthedataandviewlayout

Comment: The linked article is deleted: "Contact your space administrator if you would like it restored."

Comment: It's more useful if you put the actual answer in your answer.

Comment: down-voting a 2.5yr old response to a question is kinda pointless. The platform has evolved so much that even if i did enter the answer here... it would probable be wrong by now